# Rails Authorization Plugin Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, rails-authorization

I'm trying to get the `permit` method to work using the [rails-authorization-plugin](http://github.com/DocSavage/rails-authorization-plugin) and [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic), and I keep running into this error:

When I try:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  before_filter permit 'admin'
  ...
```

I get this:

```
Authorization::CannotObtainUserObject in HomeController#index
Couldn't find #current_user or @user, and nothing appropriate found in hash
```

Now I do have my `current_user` method setup, and it works, because I used it just about everywhere else in my app:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...

  helper_method :current_user

  private

  def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end

  def current_user
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
    @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
  end

  ...
```

I also know that I have users with the appropriate roles in my database, because this method works:

```
def require_admin
   unless current_user.is_admin? || current_user.is_root?
      flash[:warning] = 'You are not an administrator and cannot access this page.'
      redirect_to root_path
   end
end
```

I can make everything work if I just check on the user level using this:

```
before_filter :require_admin, :only => 'index'
```

... but shouldn't I be able to the same thing effectively with `permit` and `permit?`?

Any help would be much appreciated. Let me know if you need to see more code and I'll be happy to post it. There really is nothing on Google that I can make heads-or-tails of regarding getting these two systems to work with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured it out.

As Jared correctly pointed out, the proper usage is

```
permit 'admin'
```

(Not as part of a `before_filter`).

HOWEVER...

... the default `:get_user_method` is set to `#current_user`, which is what the `acts_as_authenticated` plugin uses.  I, as noted earlier, am using AuthLogic, in where I have the method defined as `current_user` (without the pound sign).

So, I had tried the following:

```
permit 'admin', :get_user_method => current_user
```

Only to be greeted by a nice error message explaining that I had no such variable or method. What I was missing, however, is that the hash option takes a **string**, not a direct call to the method!! (stupid mistake, I know!)

So

```
permit 'admin', :get_user_method => 'current_user'
```

... seems to work for me.

I love Ruby and Rails, but sometimes its simplicity can be a curse of its own; I always get owned by the simple things. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the plugin incorrectly. It should not be placed in a before filter.

On the global level, you simply declare:

```
permit 'admin'
```

That's it.

All of your actions will look for a current_user or @user object and redirect to the login page if not.

On a per-action level, you use it as a block:

```
def index
  permit 'admin' do
    @some_models = SomeModel.all
  end
end
```

Comment: I changed it like you suggested (on the global level) so now it just reads `permit 'admin'`, but I'm still getting the same error. I get the same error when I try to do it on a per-action level. ??